# MATLAB: for loop changes sizing of matrix?

Tags: matlab, math, kinematics

I'm trying to linearize a state space model. Using the circshift function I'm trying to derive each element individually and add it all into one 12x12 matrix. In the for loop the code runs normally but then its as if the left side of the equation goes from an expected 4x3 to a 12x1.

```
clc 
clear

g = 9.8067;
m = 1.121;
cd = .23;
Jx = .01;
Jy = .0082;
Jz = .0148;
u=0;
UAV = 1;

JBx = (Jy - Jz)/Jx;
JBy = (Jz - Jx)/Jy;
JBz = (Jx - Jy)/Jz;

Un = [m*g, 0, 0, 0]';
Xn = [0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]';
delta = 0.001;

deltaX = delta*abs(Xn);
if (deltaX == 0) 
    deltaX = h;
end

deltaU = delta*abs(Un);
if (deltaU == 0) 
    deltaU = h;
end
temp = zeros(12,1);
temp(1) = 1;
Ax = zeros(12,12);
Bu = zeros(12,4);

test = QuadDynamics(Xn+circshift(temp,1)*deltaX(1),Un,UAV);
test2 = QuadDynamics(Xn,Un,UAV);
test3 = (test-test2)/deltaX(1);
%Runs correctly the first few times, then crashes because it tries to compute a 12x1 with a 4x4.
for i=1:12
    Ax(:,i) = (QuadDynamics(Xn+circshift(temp,i-1)*deltaX(i),Un,UAV) - QuadDynamics(Xn,Un,UAV))/deltaX(i);
end

for i=1:4
    Bu(:,i) = (QuadDynamics(Xn,Un+circshift(temp(1:4),i-1)*deltaU(i),UAV) - QuadDynamics(Xn,Un,UAV))/deltaU(i); 
end

A = Ax;
B = Bu;

%% Function xDot
function xDot = QuadDynamics(x,u,UAV)

    Velocity = [x(4);x(5);x(6)];
    EulerAngles = [x(7); x(8); x(9)];
    AngularRates = [x(10);x(11);x(12)];

    thrust = u(1);
    tphi = u(2);
    ttheta = u(3);
    tpsi = u(4);

    phi = EulerAngles(1);
    theta = EulerAngles(2);
    psi = EulerAngles(3);

    REBt = REB(phi, theta, psi);
    RBE = REBt';

    g = 9.8067;
    m = 1.121;
    cd = .23;
    Jx = .01;
    Jy = .0082;
    Jz = .0148;
    JBx = (Jy - Jz)/Jx;
    JBy = (Jz - Jx)/Jy;
    JBz = (Jx - Jy)/Jz;

    p = AngularRates(1);
    q = AngularRates(2);
    r = AngularRates(3);

    dPosition = Velocity';
    tempdVelocity = (1/m) * REBt * ([0; 0; -thrust] - RBE*Velocity*cd) + [0; 0; g];
    tempdEulerAngles = getN(phi, theta)*AngularRates;
    tempdAngularRates = [(JBx*q*r+(1/Jx)*tphi) (JBy*p*r + (1/Jy) * ttheta) (JBz*p*q + (1/Jz) * tpsi)];

    dVelocity = [tempdVelocity(1) tempdVelocity(2) tempdVelocity(3)];
    dEulerAngles = [tempdEulerAngles(1) tempdEulerAngles(2) tempdEulerAngles(3)];
    dAngularRates = [tempdAngularRates(1) tempdAngularRates(2) tempdAngularRates(3)];

    xDot = [dPosition; dVelocity; dEulerAngles; dAngularRates];
end

%% Function REB
function Rot = REB(phi,theta,psi)

    %Body to vehicle
    Rot = [cos(theta)*cos(psi) sin(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(psi)-cos(phi)*sin(psi) cos(phi)*sin(theta)*cos(psi)+sin(phi)*sin(psi)
           cos(theta)*sin(psi) sin(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(psi)+cos(phi)*cos(psi) cos(phi)*sin(theta)*sin(psi)-sin(phi)*cos(psi)
           -sin(theta) sin(phi)*cos(theta) cos(phi)*cos(theta) ];
end

%% Function getN
function N = getN(phi, theta)

    N = [1 sin(phi)*tan(theta) cos(phi)*tan(theta)
         0 cos(phi) -sin(phi)
         0 sin(phi)*sec(theta) cos(phi)*sec(theta)];
end
```

I've tried splitting up the equation into multiple tests and all of them come back with expected results. I'm at a loss as to what is going wrong...

Comment: What do you mean "as if"?  Left side of WHICH equation?  Do you get an error?  Where exactly, and what error?

Comment: Please try to explain more clearly what you observe. Note that we have no idea what you're working on, or what your code does. Ideally you'd post a [mre], reducing the size of the code so it focusses on the issue, and we don't need  to wade through stuff unrelated to that issue. Simplify the problem enough, and you're likely to figure it out yourself!

Comment: Additionally to the other comments, please consider debugging your code by yourself, e.g. using breakpoints.

Comment: In addition to what has been said by others, the code you provided cannot be run because `QuadDynamics` is undefined